# Is this the right way to switch scenes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have multiple scenes in my JavaFX project. It seems like each time I try to move to next scene it takes a lot of time. I just wanted to show you my code to make sure that I'm not doing anything redundant or stupid.

```
public void goToDash(Button b) throws IOException {

    Stage primaryStage = (Stage) b.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Classmate - Dashboard");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 705));//width, hight
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
}
```

The size of stage remains same in every scene but the title is changed. Any helpful tips are welcomed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you can avoid reloading the fxml file, you could potentially save some time. And judging your current code, the used fxml is not changing when switching to another scene, correct? Than you can simply preload the fxml file, and just set it as root when needed.

Comment: if you switch scenes, back and forth, a lot, you could possibly speed it up, by reading only once from the fxml, and store it in the `Parent`. Then, access it later on as you need it.

Comment: You are saying I should preload my every FXML file and use the preloaded ones each time I need to switch to another scene. This seems a smart approach. Thanks

Comment: In addition to @Shashwat 's suggestion, could you please specify: 1. how long does it usually take? (1 second? 10 seconds? more?). 2. What OS & version are you using? 3. Do the scenes contain any non-English text? If so - does it happen with English-only scenes?

Comment: Importing all classes used by name in the fxml can be more performant than using imports for packages...

Comment: @sillyfly FXML file which contain about 260 lines of code took about 5 seconds to load and another file which contains about 100 lines of code took about 2 seconds. I using Windows 8.1 64 bit Pro, Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz, RAM: 4 GB
All scenes have English text only.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it may be related to a bug which causes some specific languages to load and render much slower, but it only affects Linux.  In your case I'm guessing the searching and loading of classes may take the longest, so fabian's suggestion should help (or cache the resulting `Parent` as suggested before).